# Is there a way to access wifi password from flutter code?

Tags: android, flutter, wifi

So i have a device a want to connect to wifi. I know i can get the SSID from the network my phone is connected to, but i also want the app to find the password so user dont have to write it.

I have seen when you connect to a chromecast, the configuration app lets you pick a network form available networks, and if you choose the one your phone was connected to, the configuration app asks "Get wifi password from this mobile device?".

So my question is maybe then, how does google access the information of wifi-password, and is it possible to do this using flutter.

I have tried to find some plugins that can do this, but the closest i came whas this one: https://github.com/alternadom/WiFiFlutter
[Photo from chromcast configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPJhb.png)

Answer (score 2):

Password in Android are stored in one of the files in `/data/misc/wifi`, usually inside `wpa_supplicant.conf`. However, I also found that information inside the same folder but in a file called `WifiConfigStore.xml`.

I don't know how to get this through code, but hopefully this can be useful for you. Also note you need root privileges to access those files from adb.